# Ways of Passing Parameters to the Constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

My question is on line 72. Why can we do the same operation at line 81 without any errors? Are there any preferences that should be done if we declare an object that needs parameters to be passed to its class constructor?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class clsPerson 
{
    string _FullName;
    class clsAddress
    {
    private:
        string _AddressLine1;
        string _AddressLine2;
        string _City;
        string _Country;
    public:
        clsAddress(string AddressLine1, string AddressLine2, string City, string Country)
        {
            _AddressLine1 = AddressLine1;
            _AddressLine2 = AddressLine2;
            _City = City;
            _Country = Country;
        }
        string setAddressLine1(string AddressLine1)
        {
            _AddressLine1 = AddressLine1;
        }
        string AddressLine1()
        {
            return _AddressLine1;
        }
        string setAddressLine2(string AddressLine2)
        {
            _AddressLine2 = AddressLine2;
        }
        string AddressLine2()
        {
            return _AddressLine2;
        }
        string setCity(string City)
        {
            _City = City;
        }
        string City()
        {
            return _City;
        }
        string setCountry(string Country)
        {
            _Country = Country;
        }
        string Country()
        {
            return _Country;
        }
        void Print()
        {
            cout << "\nAddress:\n";
            cout << _AddressLine1 << endl;
            cout << _AddressLine2 << endl;
            cout << _City << endl;
            cout << _Country << endl;
        }
    };
public:
    string setFullName(string FullName)
    {
        _FullName = FullName;
    }
    string FullName()
    {
        return _FullName;
    }
    clsAddress Address = clsAddress("", "", "", "");
    // why i can't replace line 71 with => clsAddress Address ("", "", "", "");
    clsPerson(string FullName, string AddressLine1, string AddressLine2, string City, string Country)
    {
        _FullName = FullName;
        Address = clsAddress(AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Country); 
    }
};
int main()
{
    clsPerson Person1 ("Mohammed Abu-Hadhoud", "Building 10", "Queen Rania Street", "Amman", "Jordan");
    clsPerson Person1 = clsPerson ("Mohammed Abu-Hadhoud", "Building 10", "Queen Rania Street", "Amman", "Jordan");
    Person1.Address.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried both ways and they are correct out of the class, but only one way was accepted by the compiler if I declared an object inside the class.

Comment: You realize that line numbers don't show, right? You need to mark the lines in question. Although, looking closer, you're trying to do some quite incorrect stuff, and appear to have a general misunderstanding of the purpose of constructors.

Comment: Because inside of a class `clsAddress Address ( ... );` is a declaration of a method, but you are trying to declare a member variable. Outside of a class there is no such confusion.

Comment: As a minor aside, you shouldn't use names beginning with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter (eg. `_FullName`) as these are [reserved for the implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). It probably won't break anything here but it's a bad habit.

Comment: Also you should be using member initialization lists in your constructors.

Comment: Why did you delete and repost the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78244335/2752075)? We already linked you to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use *parenthesis* to initialize a class member directly in its declaration, the syntax rules don't allow it.  But, you can use *curly braces* instead, eg:

```
class clsPerson 
{
    ...
    clsAddress Address {"", "", "", ""};
    ...
};
```

Otherwise, use the *member initialization list* of the parent class's constructor to initialize a member that has a non-default constructor, eg:

```
class clsPerson 
{
    ...
public:
    clsAddress Address;

    clsPerson(string FullName, string AddressLine1, string AddressLine2, string City, string Country)
        : _FullName(FullName), Address(AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Country)
    {
    }

    ...
};
```

You can also give `clsAddress` a default constructor instead and let the compiler initialize the `std::string` members to empty strings for you (since `std::string` is itself default constructible), eg:

```
class clsAddress
{
...
public:
    clsAddress() = default;
    ...
};

class clsPerson 
{
    ...
    clsAddress Address;
    ...

    clsPerson(string FullName, string AddressLine1, string AddressLine2, string City, string Country)
    {
        _FullName = FullName;
        Address = clsAddress(AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Country)
    }
};
```

But this is less efficient since you are creating two `clsAddress` objects and copying one to the other.

---

On a side note: you have several warnings in your code about missing `return` statements in your setter methods. None of them should have a return type declared on them, use `void` instead, eg:

```
void setAddressLine1(string AddressLine1)
{
    _AddressLine1 = AddressLine1;
}

// etc ...
```

Comment: The getters should probably be tagged as `const` as well.  E.g. `string Country() const { return _country; }`

Comment: But, of course, if the setters aren't going to do any kind of checks, then what's the point in getters and setters and private member variables at all?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau
it's really not my own code, but I got a question about, so i posted this question, Your guidance means a lot to me, but i still have the question, isn't Address(object) is an object, and when declaration should i define it's own class constructor parameters, why i cant pass it's parameters the same way at Person1(object).
```
 clsAddress Address ("", "", "", "");
```
////////
```
clsPerson Person1("", "", "", "");
```
why i get error at the first and not at the second? since they are both objects

Comment: @ZiadGad I don't understand what you are asking for now. It sounds like you are just re-iterating your original question, which I already covered in the 1st sentence of my answer